# Edit UIButton text with keyboard

Tags: ios4, keyboard, uibutton, ipad

I have a UIButton that responds to a TouchUpInside event.  Inside this event handler, I want to bring up the keyboard and allow the user to edit the text of the button.  I have tried to set editing to YES as shown below, but this gives an unrecognized selector message...

```
-(void)editSelection:(id)sender
{
    [sender setEditing:YES];
}
```

Is there a way to edit text if the sender is a UIButton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a UITextField with the same frame as the button.

Answer (score 0):

best set a text field over the button ( a borderless one) - 
and then `[self.myVeryOwnButton setTitle:@"something" forControlState:UIControlStateNormal];`

something of that nature.

Comment: and you will get unrecognised selector because you are trying to call 'setEditing' on a uibutton